# Is it considered copyright infringement if I publish a book on how to do something based on what I learned at a school?

Tags: united-states, copyright, innocent-infringement

Back in 2012, I took a career exploration at [this school.](https://www.opb.org/news/article/vancouver-piano-school-blind-closing/) I was so inspired by it that I decided to write a tutorial on how it is done for the purposes of getting started, but not necessarily to replace instructions or hands-on learning.

I would like to self-publish it on the two major platforms being used, but I want to make sure I am doing it legally.

First, I indicated in the copyright notice or license agreement that this book is free to distribute for non-commercial use GNU General Public License 4.0

In the disclaimer, I indicated that the information contained herein are those of the author's research and do not represent the school in any way.

At the bottom, I gave resources, and gave credit to those at the school for having shown me the procedure.

Earlier this year, I asked a similar question about this, and I learned about the fair use argument.

Would it still be considered an infringement if I were to outline the exact steps based on what I recall, since I didn't come up with those steps originally?

Comment: Are you copying any text from the schools materials or a textbook? If they are all your own words there is no copyright issue at all.

Comment: NO, it's all in my own words. I'm not copying anything.

Comment: If you are worried for your particular circumstance, you should probably consult a lawyer.

Comment: If it is your own research and your own words, it is your copyright. You do not have to have "come up" with the steps to be the author. You just have to put them into (your own) words. Normally the academic thing to do is to cite the source of the information (where you got some kind of formula or procedure), but that is an academic issue, not a copyright issue.

Answer (score 2):

If the content you are publishing is all in your own words, you are not copying anything, and therefore not infringing on anyone's copyright.